# C# Azure blob storage dependency injection in azure function

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-blob-storage, sonarlint

In my azure function project i'm using the sonarlint Extension, i have this code for example

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs; 
public static class HttpPostSaveFilesIndexed
    {
        [FunctionName("Http_Post_Save_Files_Indexed")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorageSimem");
        }
    }
```

SonarLint Highlights this "BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorageSimem");" with the code S6420 'Client instances should not be recreated on each Azure Function invocation'.
In my mind i was thinking of creating a readonly variable at the start of the function

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
public static class HttpPostSaveFilesIndexed
    {
        private static readonly BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient
        [FunctionName("Http_Post_Save_Files_Indexed")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            blobServiceClient.something....
        }
    }
```

what is a better aproach of this? like dependency injection but i don't know how

Comment: Ref: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-6420

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](https://www.blog.devitpl.com/using-constructor-injection-to-implement-di-in-microsoft-azure/) on how to inject Blobservice client via DI, so that you don't need to create it in every http function invocation.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran your link no longer works, I receive a 404.

Comment: That is the risk of blogs is it not  ? :-)  Here is the same article - I think - because it was eight months ago - https://ishanvora.medium.com/using-constructor-injection-to-implement-di-in-microsoft-azure-dev-information-techn-6f3075f53530